# python class data descriptor list

Tags: python, descriptor

I can't seem to figure out how to get a list of a classes data descriptors. Basically, I want to run some validation against the fields and unset fields. For instance:

```
class Field (object):
    def __init__ (self, name, required=False):
        self.name = name
        self.required = required

    def __set__ (self, obj, val):
        obj.__dict__[self.name] = val

    def __get__ (self, obj):
        if obj == None:
            raise AttributeError
        if self.name not in obj.__dict__:
            raise AttributeError
        return obj.__dict__[self.name]
```

Then I wanted to implement it in a model like so:

```
class BaseModel (object):
    some_attr = Field('some_attr', required=True)
    def save (self):
        for field in fields:
            if field.required and field.name not in self.__dict__:
                raise Exeception, 'Validation Error'
```

How would I go about getting a list of the fields I define? I was thinking, I could do the following:

```
import inspect

fields = []
for attr in self.__class__.__dict__:
    if inspect.isdatadescriptor(self.__class__.__dict__[attr]):
        fields.append(attr)
```

But I ran into problems with inheritance, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to iterate over the classes' members you need to use `inpsect.getmembers`. So your last example would look like this:

```
import inspect

fields = []
for member_name, member_object in inspect.getmembers(self.__class__):
    if inspect.isdatadescriptor(member_object):
         fields.append(member_name)
```

In your `descriptor` you should replace accessing `__dict__` directly with python's  [getattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) and [setattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr) builtins.

Also, keep in mind that you want to make a distinction between the `descriptor` attribute's name on the class and the underlying instance's attribute. In cases like this I usually prepend and underscore. e.g.:

```
class Field (object):
    def __init__(self, name, required=False):
        self.name = '_' + name
        self.required = required 

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        setattr(obj, self.name, val)

    def __get__(self, obj):
        return getattr(obj, self.name)
```

Comment: I was just wondering, is it possible to make it only execute once, as the fields will not change I don't want to do it on every object instantiation.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your meaning. Is it a question of validating the class so that it only contains Field attributes? And then only doing that validation the once, at the time the class is created as opposed to every time you call 'Save'?

Comment: If that is the case, then I would consider wrapping that kind of validation within a metaclass, or perhaps a class decorator.

Comment: The getmembers function takes a predicate argument directly, so you can simplify the for loop as:  for name, descriptor in inspect.getmembers(self.__class__, inspect.isdatadescriptor):